# Haskell stack C++ linking fails

Tags: c++, haskell, haskell-stack

I am trying to write a Haskell library and am getting the error message in stack ghci:

```
ghci> functionThatCalls_cSmithNormalForm 0
ghc-9.4.5: ^^ Could not load 'csmith_normal_form', dependency unresolved. See top entry above.

GHC.ByteCode.Linker: can't find label
During interactive linking, GHCi couldn't find the following symbol:
  csmith_normal_form
```

whenever I call the function `cSmithNormalForm` which is defined in SNF.hs as:

```
foreign import ccall "csmith_normal_form" cSmithNormalForm :: Ptr CLLong -> IO (Ptr CLLong)
```

the C++ function is exported in the snf.cpp file (the only c++ file in the whole project) as:

```
using i64 = long long;
(...)
extern "C" {
    i64 *csmith_normal_form(i64[]);

    i64 *csmith_normal_form(i64 _mx[]) {
        (...)
    }
}
```

After a lot of attempts to make this link, my package.yaml file contains this:

```
cxx-sources:
- src/snf.cpp
cxx-options:
- -std=c++17

include-dirs:
- src

library:
  source-dirs: src
  cxx-sources:
  - src/snf.cpp
  cxx-options:
  - -std=c++17
  when:
    - condition: os(linux)
      extra-libraries: stdc++
```

The stack.yaml file has been left untouched. Both SNF.hs and snf.cpp lie in the same directory (src).

Despite the error, `stack build` runs successfully.

Is there a way to fix the error and successfully call the c++ function from Haskell? Also, is there any available documentation for how to use options such as cxx-options with stack? I was unable to find anything official looking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a Stack bug.  GHCi needs to have any standalone foreign `.o` files passed as arguments on the command line.  Stack inspects the Cabal `c-sources` to determine an appropriate list of C `.o` files to supply, but it doesn't inspect the `cxx-sources` line.

There are a couple possible workarounds.

First, you could try to pass the correct filename yourself with something like:

```
$ stack ghci --ghci-options $(find .stack-work -name 'snf.o')
```

Second, you could consider specifying your C++ sources in a `c-sources` line instead of a `cxx-sources` line.  Stack and Cabal are fine with C and C++ files being listed in `c-sources`, and they'll correctly identify which is which based on the file extension.  The only reason for having a `cxx-sources` field in the first place is to allow different `cc-options` and `cxx-options` fields so C and C++ files can be compiled with different flags (see the [documentation for cxx-sources](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cabal-package.html#pkg-field-cxx-sources)).